# Magento configurable product don't get the min_price of the items out of stock

Tags: configurable-product, price

I have a problem with configurable products that have simple products out of stock since magento is not taking the lower price of these simple products to assign it to the min_price of configurable. How can I make magento assign the min_price of the simple products to the min_price of conigurable even if they don't have stock